# Как задать процент в питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно сложить  5000 и 10 процентов от этой суммы в питоне

Comment: Подсчитать 10% и прибавить.

Comment: На сколько нужно умножить/разделить число чтобы получить 10%

Comment: `a = 5000; a *= 1.1` ;)

Comment: Автор, уточните вопрос.  5000%  и 10 %  от какой-то неуказанной сумы или все же 10% от 5000? У Вашего однокурсника более четко вопрос сформлирован. У Вас же он двуякотрактуем.

Answer (score 2):

Просто прописываете:

```
x = int(input()) #Вводите нужное число
res = x + (x/100*10) #Прибавляет к этому числу 10%
```

И ваша проблема решена

Answer (score 1):

Вот такое решение:

```
a = 5000
a += a * 0.1
```